# multiple threads for vector processing

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have 2 vectors with some filenames and function that process this files:

```
vector<string> vecFilenames1; // {filename1_1, filename1_2, filename1_3, ...}
vector<string> vecFilenames2; // {filename2_1, filename2_2, filename2_3, ...}
```

This vectors have same size. How I process now:

```
// function for processing
void doSomeStuff() {// ...}
// processing loop
for (int i = 0; i < vecFilenames1.size();i++) {
    doSomeStuff(vecFilenames1[i], vecFilenames2[i]);
}
```

I have 4 threads (2 cores) and I want do such a process faster, how could I do that?

**EDIT 1**

I use mingw compiler:

```
g++ (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Do I need to change it to newer version for easy solving my problem?

**EDIT 2**

I updated my gcc:

```
g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: You should specify what is the latest version of C++ and which compile(s) you can use, since one of the possible answers is the parallel overload of [`std::for_each()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), but that's C++17 onwards only, and your Standard library implementation(s) may or may not support that overload yet.

Comment: @underscore_d I can change my mingw version for having new c++17 version if you could show a little example of usage parallel overload of `std::for_each()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should partition vector into ranges and process each range in a threadpool thread.

C++17 parallel algorithms is an easy way to accomplish this. By using std algorithm, you don't need to do things like partitioning vector, and calling thread pool manually.

You can use Intel TBB library or Open MP directives to achieve similar without C++17 support.

Or roll your own implementation. `std::async` is to run a thread pool task, `std::hardware_concurrency` to get the estimate on number of cores

Example of parallel `for_each`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <execution>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

vector<string> vecFilenames1;
vector<string> vecFilenames2;

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        vecFilenames1.push_back("filename1_" + to_string(i));
        vecFilenames2.push_back("filename2_" + to_string(i));
    }

    mutex m;

    auto f = [&](const string& fn1)
    {
        // Comupute other element via pointer arthimetics
        // Works only with vector, for, say, deque, use container of struct
        const string& fn2 = vecFilenames2[&fn1 - vecFilenames1.data()];

        // simulate processing (to hide mutex unfairness and make threads
        // working concurrently)
        // replace with read processing
        using namespace chrono_literals;
        this_thread::sleep_for(30ms);

        // avoid doing any real work under the lock to benefit from paralleling
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(m);

        // ideally don't do console i/o from thread pool in real code
        cout << "Processing " << fn1 << " & " << fn2
            << " from " << this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    };

    for_each(execution::par, vecFilenames1.begin(), vecFilenames1.end(), f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to switch to gcc 9 as [cppreference tables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp17) suggest. Though C++17 parallel algorithms are not the only way. You can use Intel TBB library or Open MP directives.

Comment: Actually, gcc 9.1 https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017  (look for Parallelism TS)

Comment: Could you share with some examples of c++ 17 parallel std algorithms usage?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Did you check your code? I have an error `error: 'mutex' was not declared in this scope`. (Included <mutex> and nothing changes).PS see my 2  edit about gcc version

Comment: STL implementation tolerate to missing includes, and tolerance is different. It worked for me in MSVC. Anyway, after adding includes, it works in gcc too: https://wandbox.org/permlink/nEmyVlifJylYZGJx (though online compiler seem to be restricted from actually paralleing the code)

Comment: I needed to switch  to c++17 in MCVS :) Thank you. Is it will activate all threads (4 on 1 computer and 8 on another) I have, I do not need to change something for more threads usage?

Comment: That deserves separate question, but I'll try to answer in comments.
Parallel algorithms, as well as any other auto-paralleling techniques, will scale automatically for given hardware at implementation discretion. C++ does not give a way to control it or even know how many threads would be created. `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` is the only C++ API, and it is merely a guess how many CPU cores are there, although likely to be a good one, so parallel algorithms are likely to use its value.

Comment: MSVC's implementation use Windows threadpool, so yields this decision to the OS. `QueueUserWorkItem` function (which puts work to thread pool) is documented to create up to 512 threads by default, can be lifted.
Note also that number of CPU cores the program may utilize is another story from number of threads. By default, Windows limit is 64, can be lifted.